# how to increase root partition in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

how to extend root `/` partition by sinking swap *(previously 6gb after sinking 4Gb , unallocated 2 Gb)* and home *(previously 11 Gb after sinking 8Gb, allocated 3Gb)*. How to extend those allocated partition to root? how to combine those 5gb to `/` partition? Help me! *(this is partition extended from 30 Gb primary partition)* so if not then, how to combine another 30gb *(currently unallocated)* partition that sinked from another primary volume.

[image]

Comment: The image hasn't come through. I suppose that is a Gparted screenshot? If you try to fix that it may help.

Comment: ok i have uploaded the image ! plz help me !

Comment: Sorry, is `sda4` Windows files, and is it `sda5` you are trying to expand?. If you move the Windows files partition `sda4` to the right to near the end of the disk - **be VERY careful there...**. You might then have enough space to expand root.

Comment: how to combine those 2.62gb and 3gb unallocated partition and again combine it to "/" root ? please help me i m out of space !

Comment: Select `sda7` and move it *(You can move right or left, depends on which partition you want to expand - see [@Avinash 's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/393503/178596))*. This will take a while as it will have to transfer all of the data over to that bit of the hard disk, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Live Gparted* to re-partitioning it.Just simply move other partition to the end of the bar till the Unallocated placed behind your partition

Answer (score 0):

To add the unallocated space(2.62+3 GB)to the `dev/sda7` partition follow the given steps below,

- Boot ubuntu live disk and install gparted partition editor.
- Open gparted and right-click on the `/dev/sda7` partition to select Resize/Move option.
- click on  the left and right arrows and move it to the extreme left and right.So that the unallocated space above and below sda7 will be occupied.
- After extending apply the changes.

Comment: I think `sda7` may be the home partition :-s